# Perforce client is throwing "workspacename validation failed" error on Windows desktop

Tags: perforce

I have installed P4V client in my Windows Desktop and tried to pull a repo from Perforce server. When I selected the folder under **//depot** to be mapped under my work_space, it is throwing the below error:

```
Syntax:
C:\Users\revarath>p4 client -o <Workspace Name> | p4 client -i

C:\Users\revarath>p4 client -o revarath_ftl | p4 client -i
```

**Error in client specification.
'workspacename' validation failed: Do not use //... or //depot/... in your client view!**

I got the above error. AS I am new to Perforce tool, I didnt understand how to proceed further. Anyone faced similar issue and got solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

In cmd prompt, enter the command **p4 client**

A temp text file will be opened. Edit the below line

**Before changes:**

```
View:
    //depot/... //revarath_ftl/...
```

**After changes:**

```
View:
    //depot/firepower/ims/FTL_DEV_PRIV/feature-test-lib/... //revarath_ftl/firepower/ims/FTL_DEV_PRIV/feature-test-lib/...
```

Once done, save and close the file. 
Now I am able to pull the repo successfully.